When sorting data per category the app freezes
I have an app that saves verses (items) into my app db using floor from my own api so that use can access them offline. My minimalistic code is as follows:
verse.dart
@Entity(tableName: AppConstants.versesTable)
@JsonSerializable()
class Verse {
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
  int? rid;
  int? book;
  String? content;
  bool? bookmarked;

  Verse({
    this.book,
    this.content,
    this.bookmarked
  });

  factory Verse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$VerseFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$VerseToJson(this);
}

verses_dao.dart
@dao
abstract class VersesDao {
  @Query('SELECT * FROM ${AppConstants.versesTable}')
  Future<List<Verse>> fetchVerses();
}

home_screen.dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late HomeBloc _bloc;

  int setBook = 0;
  List<Verse> filtered = [];
  static const _pageSize = 20;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = context.read<HomeBloc>();
    _bloc.add(const HomeFetchData());
  }

  void sortVerses(List<Verse> verses, int bookNo) async {
    var tempList = await compute(
      sortVersesByBook,
      VerseSort(bookNo, verses),
    );
    setState(() => filtered = tempList);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
      bloc: _bloc,
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.status == Status.loaded) {
          setState(() => setBook = 0);
          sortVerses(state.verses, state.books[setBook].bookNo!);
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        var booksList = SizedBox(
          height: 40,
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            itemCount: state.books.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final Book book = state.books[index];
              return BookItem(
                text: book.title!,
                isSelected: setBook == index,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() => setBook = index);
                  sortVerses(state.verses, state.books[setBook].bookNo!);
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        );

        var versesList = ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Sizes.xs),
          itemCount: filtered.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return VerseItem(
              verse: filtered[index],
            );
          }
        );

        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text(AppConstants.appTitle),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                if (state.status == Status.inProgress) ...[
                  const ListLoading()
                ] else ...[
                  if (state.books.isNotEmpty) ...[booksList],
                  if (state.verses.isNotEmpty) ...[
                    versesList
                  ] else ...[
                    const EmptyState(title: "It's empty here.")
                  ],
                ]
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class VerseSort {
  int bookNo;
  List<Verse> verses;

  VerseSort(this.bookNo, this.verses);
}

List<Verse> sortVersesByBook(VerseSort verseSort) {
  return verseSort.verses
      .where((s) => s.book == verseSort.bookNo)
      .toList();
}

When the app launches it fetches about 700 items from the database. This is is all okay until I decide to sort the items in categories in this case books. It freezes until the sorting is done.

It is due to the sorting operation being performed on the main UI thread, causing the UI to become unresponsive. Try yo make method like...
Future<List> sortData(List data) async {
// Perform sorting asynchronously
await Future.delayed(Duration.zero); // This line is added to allow other tasks to run first
data.sort();
}

I tried to do this inside my bloc but still not much difference. But let me try what you advised.
